# Count Rows based on 2 fields grouped

Tags: pandas, group-by, count, size, cumsum

I am trying to recreate the MultiRow tool used in Alteryx.
I would like to group the data by two columns (DATE, CALL_ID) and then do a running count per row for each group.
I'm using the groupby but I don't think that's right because I don't want the output to be grouped and I don't want the data to be aggregated, I want each row to still exist.

Example Data:

```
DATE        CALL_ID   
2023-11-21  29933702  
2023-11-21  29933703    
2023-11-21  29933703    
2023-11-21  29933704    
2023-11-21  29933704
2023-11-22  29933704
```

I want the output to be:

```
DATE        CALL_ID    COUNT
2023-11-21  29933702    1
2023-11-21  29933703    1
2023-11-21  29933703    2
2023-11-21  29933704    1
2023-11-21  29933704    2
2023-11-22  29933704    1
```

OUTPUT

```
#My code: 
g = df.groupby(['DATE','CALL_ID']).size()

DATE        CALL_ID 
2023-11-21  29933702    1
            29933703    2
            29933704    2
2023-11-22  29933704    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `cumcount`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE':['2023-11-21']*5, 'CALL_ID': [29933702, 29933703, 29933703, 29933704, 29933704]})

df['COUNT'] = df.groupby(['DATE', 'CALL_ID']).cumcount() + 1

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         DATE   CALL_ID  COUNT
0  2023-11-21  29933702      1
1  2023-11-21  29933703      1
2  2023-11-21  29933703      2
3  2023-11-21  29933704      1
4  2023-11-21  29933704      2
```